# Is there a way to test Chrome Custom Tabs with Espresso?

Tags: android, listview, android-espresso, chrome-custom-tabs

Here is the stub of the code.

Click data item on `ListView` .  Works as designed and opens *Chrome Custom Tab* :

```
onData(anything()).inAdapterView(withId(R.id.listView))
                                       .atPosition(0).perform(click());

Pause(5000);
Espresso.pressBack();
```

Cannot seem to evaluate anything in the tab or even hit device back button. 
Getting this error

```
Error : android.support.test.espresso.NoActivityResumedException: No 
activities  in stage RESUMED.
```

Did you forget to launch the activity. (`test.getActivity()`  or similar)?

Comment: Please edit your post so that it can be understood without guessing. And consider posting a [mcve] - this helps to understand your problem!

Comment: I also got the same problem

Comment: Also the same problem here.

Answer (score 3):

You can use UIAutomator (https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-automator.html).  You can actually use both Espresso and UIAutomator at the same time.  See the accepted answer on the following post for more information:
[How to access elements on external website using Espresso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45379121/how-to-access-elements-on-external-website-using-espresso)

Answer (score 2):

You can prevent opening Custom Tabs and then just assert whether the intent you are launching is correct:

```
fun stubWebView(uri: String) {
    Intents.intending(allOf(IntentMatchers.hasAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW), IntentMatchers.hasData(uri)))
        .respondWith(Instrumentation.ActivityResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, null))
}

fun isNavigatedToWebView(uri: String) {
    Intents.intended(allOf(IntentMatchers.hasAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW), IntentMatchers.hasData(uri)))
}
```

This way you can avoid `Espresso.pressBack()` in your test.

Note that since these are using Espresso Intents, you need to either use `IntentsTestRule` or wrap these with Intents.init and release like this

```
fun intents(func: () -> Unit) {
    Intents.init()

    try {
        func()
    } finally {
        Intents.release()
    }
}

intents {
    stubWebView(uri = "https://www.example.com")
    doSomethingSuchAsClickingAButton()
    isNavigatedToWebView(uri = "https://www.example.com")
}
```

Comment: If you want you can also remove the `IntentMatchers.hasData(uri)` from the `stubWebView()` function and prevent opening *any* WebView (regardless of the URI).

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion for improved readability following Mustafa [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69092510/4664567):

```
intents{
    Intents.intended(
        CoreMatchers.allOf(
            IntentMatchers.hasAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW),
            IntentMatchers.hasPackage("com.android.chrome")
        )

    )
}
```